# Mysql join query fro three tables with foreign key relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table called as customers , customer_contacts, customer_sites.

Customer Table:

[image]

Customer_contacts:

[image]

Customer_sites:

[image]

I want the customer data to be displayed if there is no related data in the other two tables.But with my query i m not getting the results.
Below is the query:

```
SELECT c.id,c.customer_code,c.customer_name,count(cs.customer_id) as count, cc.name,cc.email,cc.phone
from customers as c
left join customer_sites as cs on cs.customer_id = c.id
left join customer_contacts as cc on cc.customer_id = c.id
where cc.is_main =1 group by cc.id
```

Result what i m getting :

[image]

But i m getting only two rows of data not all . I need the all data to displayed if there is no data in other tables .any suggestions please.

Comment: Move the where clause to the join for CC.  The where clause is in essence eliminating the nulls created by the left join; making the left join act like an inner join. Replace `where` with `and` and you're good.  I'm also not a big fan of group by w/o listing all the fields in the select that are not aggregated.  So I'd add those fields not aggregated in the select to the group by.

Comment: @xQbert : i have done replacing where with and , throwing error for me :(

Comment: `GROUP BY c.id
         , c.customer_code
         , c.customer_name
         , cc.name
         , cc.email
         , cc.phone`  Prior version of mySQL defaulted to using group by extensions.  The current version disabled that feature.  So now the engine requires you to list all the non-aggregrated fields from the select in the group by. (unless you re-enable the feature) but I never really found value in it personally; given a well designed database/query.

Comment: @xQbert : Thanks it worked for me group by all

Comment: Please add expected results to your question as the count() really doesn't make sense and displaying expected results would help clarify the question.  I'm not sure my "GROUP BY" achieves the correct count for what you're after.  (Just because it runs, doesn't mean it's right!)

Comment: @xQbert : yeah thank you will do it

Answer (score 1):

Add the where to your on clause:

```
SELECT c.id,c.customer_code,c.customer_name,count(cs.customer_id) as count, cc.name,cc.email,cc.phone
from customers as c
left join customer_sites as cs on cs.customer_id = c.id
left join customer_contacts as cc on cc.customer_id = c.id and cc.is_main =1
 group by cc.id
```

If you do not do it, your `left join` will be an `inner join`.

also you can not use columns in the select clause, which are not in a Aggregate function and not part of the `Group by` clause.

Comment: @5367683 And the message is?

Comment: `Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mac.c.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
`

Comment: @5367683 Your Group by makes no sence

Comment: then how do i get the data ?

Comment: What sould be the `count`?

Comment: `Count` should be all rows of `customer_sites` where customer id mataches

Comment: then you have to use nested queries

Comment: How do i do nested queries ?